# There is a problem with the control code of bmp280

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi

May I ask you strong, where is the problem of my bmp280 control code? The temperature and pressure readings are unchanged. The numbers aren't right either. Is there something wrong with the initialization? Or is it a matter of calculation? I use Raspberry PI 4b. But after I ran someone else's code once, the readings returned to normal, and after restarting, they still didn't work. I ask for your help.

```
#ifndef BMP280_H
#define BMP280_H
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
class BMP280
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    BMP280(int bus, int address);
    ~BMP280();
    void init();
    void getData();
    void calculateAltitude(double pressure);
    // void write_reg(uint8_t reg, std::vector<uint8_t> val);
    void write_reg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t val);
    uint8_t read_reg(uint8_t reg);
    unsigned short dig_t1, dig_p1;
    signed short dig_t2, dig_t3, dig_p2, dig_p3, dig_p4;
    signed short dig_p5, dig_p6, dig_p7, dig_p8, dig_p9;
    double  var1, var2;
    uint8_t msb, lsb, xlsb;
    int fd;
    double pressdata;
    double tempdata;
    double altitudedata;
};
#endif
```

```
#include "BMP280.h"

BMP280::BMP280(int bus, int address)
{
    char filename[20];
    snprintf(filename, 19, "/dev/i2c-%d", bus);
    fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open the I2C bus.";
    }
        
    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, address) < 0) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to acquire bus access or talk to slave." ;
    }
}

BMP280::~BMP280()
{
}
void BMP280::init()
{
    
    write_reg(0xe0,0xb6);
    usleep(5000);
    
    dig_t1 = (read_reg(0x89) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x88); 
    dig_t2 = (read_reg(0x8b) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x8a); 
    dig_t3 = (read_reg(0x8d) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x8c); 
    dig_p1 = (read_reg(0x8f) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x8e); 
    dig_p2 = (read_reg(0x91) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x90); 
    dig_p3 = (read_reg(0x93) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x92);
    dig_p4 = (read_reg(0x95) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x94);
    dig_p5 = (read_reg(0x97) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x96);
    dig_p6 = (read_reg(0x99) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x98);
    dig_p7 = (read_reg(0x9b) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x9a);
    dig_p8 = (read_reg(0x9d) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x9c);
    dig_p9 = (read_reg(0x9f) << 8)
            | read_reg(0x9e);

    
    write_reg(0xf4,0x27);
    usleep(5000);
    write_reg(0xf4,0x24);
    usleep(5000);
    write_reg(0xf5,0x00);
    usleep(5000);
    write_reg(0xf4,0x27);
    usleep(5000);
}

uint8_t BMP280::read_reg(uint8_t reg) 
{
    uint8_t buf=0;
    if(write(fd, &reg, sizeof(reg)) != sizeof(reg)) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to write to the I2C bus.";
    }
    if(read(fd, &buf,1) != 1) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to read from the I2C bus.";
    }
    return buf;
}
void BMP280::write_reg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t val) 
{
    if(write(fd, &reg, sizeof(reg)) != sizeof(reg)) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to write to the I2C bus.";
    }
    if(write(fd, &val, sizeof(val)) != sizeof(val)) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to write to the I2C bus.";
    }
}
void BMP280::getData()
{
    msb = read_reg(0xf7);
    lsb = read_reg(0xf8);
    xlsb = read_reg(0xf9);
    uint32_t pressure_raw = (msb << 16 | lsb << 8 | xlsb) >> 4;
    msb = read_reg(0xfa);
    lsb = read_reg(0xfb);
    xlsb = read_reg(0xfc);
    uint32_t temperature_raw = (msb << 16 | lsb << 8 | xlsb) >> 4;
    var1 = (((double)temperature_raw) / 16384.0 - ((double)dig_t1) / 1024.0)*((double)dig_t2);
    var2 = ((((double)temperature_raw) / 131072.0 - ((double)dig_t1) / 8192.0)*(((double)temperature_raw) / 131072.0 - ((double)dig_t1) / 8192.0))*((double)dig_t3);
    double fine = var1 + var2;
    int zz=var1 + var2;
    tempdata =fine/5120.0;
    // tempdata =temp;

    var1 = ((double)zz / 2.0) - 64000.0;
    var2 = var1 * var1*((double)dig_p6) / 32768.0;
    var2 = var2 + var1 * ((double)dig_p5)*2.0;
    var2 = (var2 / 4.0) + (((double)dig_p4)*65536.0);
    var1 = (((double)dig_p3)*var1*var1 / 524288.0 + ((double)dig_p2)*var1) / 524288.0;
    var1 = (1.0 + var1 / 32768.0)*((double)dig_p1);
    if (var1==0)
    {
        return ;
    }
    
    pressdata = 1048576.0 - ((double)pressure_raw);
    pressdata = (pressdata - (var2 / 4096.0))*6250.0 / var1;
    var1 = ((double)dig_p9)*pressdata*pressdata / 2147483648.0;
    var2 = pressdata * ((double)dig_p8) / 32768.0;
    pressdata = pressdata + (var1 + var2 + ((double)dig_p7)) / 16.0;
    pressdata=pressdata/1000;
}

void BMP280::calculateAltitude(double pressure) 
{
    altitudedata=44300*(1 - pow(pressure / 101.325, 1/5.256));
}
```

Comment: You may want to replace `unsigned short` with `uint16_t` and `signed short` with `int16_t`.  Remember that the default integer types are based on range not on implementation size.  You are already using `uint8_t`, so continue the practice with the other integers.

Comment: You need to use a debugger and find the statement that is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, bro. My code level is very low.